# Regular Expression substring start and end with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

**"/upload/c_fill,w_960,h_640/v1430399111/"**

Where i want to replace wherever **"w_"** to some other value, say w_960 to w_930 while 960 could be vary.

i tried following but not able to find string end with:

```
var imgPath = elemPath.replace(/(\,w_)/, ",w_"+930);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show several examples of "before" and "after" strings, i.e. the input and desired output.

Comment: what you actually want to replace can you please say that with more example. .?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you wanted to replace `,w_` followed by three digits with `,w_930`. You were on the right track. You can use `\d` to match a digit and `{3}` for three repetitions. Also you don't need the group `()` or to escape the comma:

```
var imgPath = elemPath.replace(/,w_\d{3}/, ",w_"+930);
```

If the number of digits can vary, use `+` (one or more repetitions):

```
var imgPath = elemPath.replace(/,w_\d+/, ",w_"+930);
```